# Width and height with divs (percantage)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create simple web page using divs. I have read a lot of articles, but everythere width and height of divs is specified in px. Maybe I don't understand something, but maybe it is better to specify this attributes in percantage ?
I have tried, but received not what expected.
I need to get such result 
[image: Desired]

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
<!-- HEADER -->
        <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">Logo</div>
        <div id="top_info">Top Info</div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="404.html">First</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">Third</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">Fourth</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">Fifth</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">Sixth</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
</div>
    <div id="content_data">
        <div id="banner">Banner</div>
        <div id="left_col">Left column</div>
        <div id="content">Contnent area</div>
        <div id="right_col">Right column</div>
    </div>
     <div id="footer">
        Footer
        </div>   

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is css file

```
#container {
 width: 90%;   
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
#header {
 width: 100%;   
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    background: #333;
}
#logo {
 float:left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#top_info {
 float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #666;
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    margin: 10px;
}
#navbar {
 height: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
#navbar ul {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#navbar ul li {
 clear: both;
}
#footer {
 padding: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
#navbar ul li a {
 font-size:12px; float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    display: block;
}
#banner {
 background: #666; 
    height: 120px;
    clear: both;
}
#content {
    width : 60%; 
}
#left_col {
 float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #000;
}
#right_col {
    background: #000;
 float: right;
        width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #FFF;

}
```

But get next result. If set width of container id in pixels it works great. 
[image]
Please help to solve the problem if its possible.
And give some advices how to build responsible pages, maybe some articles or books.
Thx.

**UPDATE**

I have changed width to 50% and it works. I guess this is because of parrent div has width 90%, so 20%(left) + 20%(right) + 50% (content) = 90%. Am I right ?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: percentages work ok, but when you start adding borders and stuff you start running into trubbel as `@Aleš Lulák` said.  remove all bourders and you should see what you want (on full screen at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that left and right columns have set border 1px. It makes their width 20% + 2 px (left and right 1px border). Also content area should be floated too.

EDIT: if you want these borders, set width of columns as follows:

```
width: calc(20% - 2px);
```

Comment: So it is best practice to use percantage instead of pixels ?

Answer (score 0):

Using percentages is one way to create a responsive web page but the better way is by using Media Queries.

Take a look at CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

They are exactly what you need. All you need to do is specify some maximum or minimum screen dimensions in your case for each media-query. This way, you can design how your site looks on mobile devices, tablets, computers, etc. and they need not all be the same!

Something that looks good on a big screen like that of a computer need not necessarily look good on a mobile device but using media query, you can design separate versions for both devices!

For example, you execute some CSS only for desktop computers using `min-width`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of more than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of less than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

This way, your webpage looks different on desktop computers and looks different on mobile devices and tablets.

Also, see [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) great link.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right.
Your percentages should add up to 100%

> 20%(left) + 20%(right) + 50% (content) = 90% **(not 100%)**

You could make the left and right percentages 25% each to get 100%. That should work fine.

Comment: Percentage is with respect to its direct parent

Answer (score -1):

The percentage is with respect to its direct parent. So it doesn't matter if parent is set to 90%. It's because of the 1px border on the side divs. which makes the divs a little bigger than 20%, going over 100% of parent.

You can solve this by make content little smaller to make space for the extra 4px due to the 1px borders on both side divs:

```
#content {
    width : 58%; 
    float: left;
}
```

It is cleaner to float all divs left. You'll get the same result.